# jQuery ajax call not working in IE

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I'm trying to get some json from a remote server using jquery's ajax-function.

```
var self = $(this);
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: *external url*,
    data: {param: self.val()},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This works fine in Chrome, the data gets output. In firefox, the request is sent, but no data is written to the console. In IE, the call does not seem to be sent at all.

What am I doing wrong? I know about cross-domain-blocking, but what puts me off is that this works in chrome but not in any other browser.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know it's working in Chrome? Try adding an `error` handler.

Comment: take out the crossdomain, does this work then?

Comment: In chrome, the success-function gets called properly, and the content is output to the console, so I figured it worked :)

Comment: @Mikau: Yeah, that's a pretty good indication. :-)

Comment: @CR41G14: If I remove that, it doesn't work in Chrome either

Comment: Changing dataType to json makes this work in Chrome and Firefox, regardless of whether crossDomain: true is present.

Answer (score 0):

> I know about cross-domain-blocking, but what puts me off is that this works in chrome but not in any other browser.

It sounds like the server you're requesting the data from supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), but keep in mind that different browsers may send different headers along with requests, and CORS requests will fail if a browser sends a header that the server doesn't say is okay. So it's entirely possible that Chrome is only sending headers the server has approved, and so the request works, but that Firefox is sending a header the server doesn't approve, and so the request doesn't work.

Unless you're using IE10, IE probably isn't working because cross-domain requests don't work in IE unless you use the `XDomainRequest` object instead of the `XMLHttpRequest` object, and jQuery doesn't do that. There are patches that make it do that, but the jQuery library itself does not. IE10 *finally* enables CORS via the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: I'm on IE9, so it might be that, and in that case, the request wouldn't ever be sent either, correct? And is there some way to work around that without patching jQuery?

Comment: @Mikau: I don't know at what point IE9 enforces the SOP when using `XMLHttpRequest`, but it would be reasonable to enforce it by not sending it at all, yes. The only workarounds are to use `XDomainRequest` directly yourself, patch jQuery (a quick search should find something), or bypass the SOP entirely by not using ajax at all (perhaps try [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), if the server supports that -- and if it supports CORS, and is giving you JSON, I'd expect it to have a JSONP option as well).